# How I add new endpoints to my VM on new azure portal (preview)?

Tags: azure

How I add new endpoints to my VM on new azure portal (preview)?

on old portal it was easy and there is tab for it, but with new one I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: This should be on ServerFault. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 108):

You can find it in Network security group section.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please consider this as correct answer. The entrypoint mapping is much more difficult to find in the new ui than at the old ui but it is still possible

Comment: I'm probably overstating this but I REALLY didn't like the change of things in the portal. Anyway, thanks a lot for this answer :)

Comment: how to change ssh port from default 22 to a custom one?

Comment: Getting to endpoints has changed yet again. Steps to find them can be found in this article for deploying Meteor to Azure: https://medium.com/@adammoisa/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-app-to-an-azure-vm-with-mup-on-the-new-azure-interface-da49652a59d

Answer (score 51):

Select Virtual Machine -> Click Resource Group -> Click All settings -> Choose the one with a blue shield icon (3rd item) ->  Click All Settings -> Click Inbound security rules -> Click the Plus icon on top.

http://blog.keithics.com/mongodb-and-node-endpoints-with-new-azure-portal/

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the way on new portal. this is the right answer and you saved my hours man :)

Comment: Just a note, that shield bit is the "Network Security Group".

Comment: Getting to endpoints has changed yet again. Steps to find them can be found in this article for deploying Meteor to Azure: https://medium.com/@adammoisa/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-app-to-an-azure-vm-with-mup-on-the-new-azure-interface-da49652a59d

Answer (score 6):

For Classic VMs, answers given b others are valid. If you are not on a classic VM, here is the path for Inbound / Outbound Rules.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Same in preview portal. Just navigate to Virtual Machines, select VMs, All settings (or Settings button in action bar):

[image]

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: This is the case as long as your VM was created as "classic". When not created as classic (which is not the recommended default in the portal), Endpoints does not appear as an option under all settings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for v2 VMs the process for exposing endpoints is slightly different. V2 VMs no longer sit inside a cloud service, instead they are deployed into a VNET. If you want to be able to access the VM outside the VNET then you can deploy a VM with a public ip address. If you do that then the VM firewall is what protects the VM, In addition you can also apply Network Security groups around the VM NIC or the subnet the VM sits in to apply additional network security around it.

Answer (score 1):

Getting to endpoints has changed yet again.

Here are the basic steps to get to endpoints:
Virtual Machines -> your machine -> overview -> resource group -> -nsg (little shield) -> inbound security rules.

Detailed steps to find the endpoints with images can be found in this article for deploying Meteor to Azure: https://medium.com/@adammoisa/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-app-to-an-azure-vm-with-mup-on-the-new-azure-interface-da49652a59d

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

For the new Virtual Machines in the azure preview portal, you should be able to open up firewall endpoints by using inbuilt 'Windows Firewall With Advanced Security'