# Where is the web url of my VM?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a web server with a VM.

I installed IIS and am trying to follow [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) to add a CNAME record and use my custom domain name to point to my VM. However I can't find the web url of my VM as explained here:

[image: From the article]

What is the correct way to setup a domain name to point to a VM on Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong documentation, the article is for PaaS services, not for an IaaS vm.

For example look here for more info on setting the Network Security Group NSG: [IIS/HTTP Endpoint on Azure VM (non-classic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251382/iis-http-endpoint-on-azure-vm-non-classic)

Comment: thanks, I did all that and still can't connect to my vm website from a browser, not even with its IP...